# Updating .sty files in ~/texmf

Tags: packages, texlive, linux, texmf

I am using **TeX Live** on **Linux Mint 17.2**, and I have previously set up the `~/texmf` directory, so that I can manually install my own `.sty` files. However, after editing the `.sty` files in `~/texmf`, LaTeX will not update with the changes.

I have attempted running `sudo texhash` and `sudo texhash ~/texmf` , but neither will update. I know that the `~/texmf` directory is still working, because I can simply rename the `.sty` file to a name that hasn't been used; I just do not want to have something along the lines of `mystyle24.sty`, after making 23 changes.

Is there a practical way of updating TeX with new versions of files in `~/texmf`?

Comment: Unless you have altered the default settings, `texhash` is pointless, at best, when applied to `~/texmf`. TeX searches the directory for files on disk. (Moreover, you wouldn't need to run `texhash` after editing the contents of an existing file anyway, even if TeX did use a database to search there.) The behaviour you describe is not standard. To update a file in my `~/texmf` I simply edit the file. I am assuming that `~/texmf` is the directory given by `kpsewhich -var TEXMFHOME`. If not, that would be different.

Comment: `~/texmf` must mimic the proper TeX Directory Structure (TDS). So: are you actually putting your LaTeX files in a subdirectory like `~/texmf/tex/latex/` (e.g.,  `~/texmf/tex/latex/myfile.sty`)?

Comment: @cfr Thank you for explaining the purpose for texhash. Seeing as this behavior is nonstandard, is there anything I could do to fix it, without uninstalling TeX?

Also, yes, `~/texmf` is the directory given by `kpse -var TEXMFHOME`.

Comment: @jon I am storing the `.sty` files in the following way:

`~/texmf/tex/style/style.sty`

This method has worked thus far for initial `.sty` files, but updating them is where the issue arises.

Comment: After hearing that this behavior is not standard, I attempted to edit other `.sty` files, and TeX seemed to behave properly. That being said, this problem is not indicative of every `.sty` file in `~/texmf`.

This problem is only happening for a particular `.sty` file. In case this were to happen again, is there any way to reset TeX -- make it "forget" about installed packages?

Comment: Well the simplest answer is to do what the TDS expects and use `~/texmf/tex/latex/style/style.sty`, which makes sense if you are writing *LaTeX* documents. Otherwise, you will need to do things like edit `texmf.cnf`, but I don't see the advantage.  I'm not sure from your description what is and is not working, but I'm fairly certain that the minor change I suggested is the easiest (and most portable!) solution.

Comment: I am not sure what changes you are making. Do drastic ones. If you have a `\maketitle` in your own package, comment it out and do `\newcommand{\maketitle}{No, i will not make a title for you}`. That way, you see that something is obviously changing.